# Description of bound variables in a Hyperledger Composer ACL condition

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I'm trying to determine what variables are bound in a Hyperledger Composer ACL condition.  The documentation just says the condition is a Boolean JavaScript expression over bound variables.  Where can I find out what variables around bound?

Answer (score 0):

```
rule R2 {
    description: "regulator with ID Bill can not update a Car if they own it"
    participant(r): "org.example.Regulator#Bill"
    operation: UPDATE
    resource(c): "org.example.Car"
    condition: (c.owner == r)
    action: DENY
}
```

`r` is a variable bound to the participant, `c` is a variable bound to the resource
Hopefully you are asking because you are trying to move off an existing composer implementation as Composer is now end of life.

Comment: What's missing from the documentation is the explicit description of participant(xyz) and resource(qrz), that those were declaring bound variables.  At least I didn't see it in the docs.  One sort of has to infer that from the example.

Comment: Composer is end of life, so it doesn't matter now. If you already have a system using it you should be migrating off of composer. You shouldn't be trying to use composer anymore.

Comment: Thanks, but it matters to me as I'm trying to understand the security model Composer used.  I'm not using Composer nor do I plan on using it.

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't anyone involved in composer anymore. All that is left for people to help themselves is to look at the source code